# Creating a slide in div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I am trying to create a div with 2 buttons. click the first button and a nother div slides in from the left. It has a button that when clicked makes it slide back off screen. Same for the second button in the main div. Only when the second button is clicked a div slides in from the right. Again with a button that makes it slide back off screen.

This is all done in jquery.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong here?

jquery:

```
var boxWidth = $("#port2").width();

$('#left').on('click',function(){
    $('#port1').animate({left:'8'});
});

$('#right').on('click',function(){
    $('#port2').animate({(right:'100%'-boxWidth});
})

$('#leftC').on('click',function(){
    $('#port1').animate({right:'100%'});
});

$('#rightC').on('click',function(){
    $('#port2').animate({left:'100%'});
});
```

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="port1">
        Left text goes here
        <button id='leftC'>Close 1</button>
    </div>
    <div id="port2">
        Right text goes here
        <button id='rightC'>Close</button>
    </div>
    <div id="text">
        good stuff goes here
        <br />
        <button id='left'>Left</button>
        <br />
        <button id='right'>Right</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#text{
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.2em;
    padding:25px;
}

#text button{
    margin: 20px 0px 10px;
}

#port1{
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:green;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.2em;
    padding:25px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-100%
}

#port2{
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.2em;
    padding:25px;
    position:absolute;
    right:-100%;
}
```

You can see it in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/belotte/vmu59h87/19/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Please look at the fiddle 
[See JsFiddle demo here ][http://jsfiddle.net/vmu59h87/21/]


  [1]:
```

All that you were doing wrong here is you are setting wrong values for left and right from your javascript. I just changed the values and everything works fine.

```
$('#left').on('click',function(){
    $('#port1').animate({left:'0'});
});
$('#right').on('click',function(){
    $('#port2').animate({right:'-30'});
});

$('#leftC').on('click',function(){console.log(">>>>>");
    $('#port1').animate({left:'-535'});
});

$('#rightC').on('click',function(){
    $('#port2').animate({right:'-535'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmu59h87/23/) Here is the working sample. You have revert the right and left values in animate method to the orignal values as set in port1 and port2 classes when closing the divs. here is the code and running snippet.

```js
//$('#port1').hide();
//$('#port2').hide();



$('#left').on('click', function() {
  $('#port1').animate({
    left: '8'
  });
});

$('#right').on('click', function() {
  $('#port2').animate({
    right: '100'
  });
});

$('#leftC').on('click', function() {
  $('#port1').animate({
    left: '-100%'
  });
});

$('#rightC').on('click', function() {
  $('#port2').animate({
    right: '-100%'
  });
});


/*
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
*/
```

```css
#text {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 25px;
}
#text button {
  margin: 20px 0px 10px;
}
#port1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%
}
#port2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="port1">
    Left text goes here
    <button id='leftC'>Close 1</button>
  </div>
  <div id="port2">
    Right text goes here
    <button id='rightC'>Close</button>
  </div>
  <div id="text">
    good stuff goes here
    <br />
    <button id='left'>Left</button>
    <br />
    <button id='right'>Right</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vmu59h87/22/)

The fiddle which is given by Ekansh is getting failed when the right btn is clicked for the second time (reason is right, left css clash i guess).

```
$('#left').on('click',function(){
    console.log( $('#port1').css('left'));
    $('#port2').removeAttr('style');
    $('#port1').animate({left:'8'});
});

$('#right').on('click',function(){
    console.log( $('#port2').css('right')+'right');
    $('#port2').removeAttr('style');
    $('#port2').animate({right:'-39px'});
});

$('#leftC').on('click',function(){
    $('#port1').animate({left:'-532px'});
});

$('#rightC').on('click',function(){
    $('#port2').animate({right:'-529px'});
});
```